# How to configure Bitvise SSH Server，make the process run in the front end

Tags: python, windows, ssh, paramiko

Install bitvise(ssh server services) in windows7, but i use python paramiko remote  call program, are executed in the backend. i want it executed in front end. how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the (SSH) servers run as a Windows service.

Window services run in a separate Windows session (google for *"Session 0 isolation"*). They cannot access interactive (user) Windows sessions.

Also note that there can be multiple user sessions (multiple logged in users) in Windows. How would the SSH server know, what user session to display the GUI on (even if it could)?

---

You can run the SSH server in an interactive Windows session, instead as a service. It has its limitations though.

---

*In general, all this (running GUI application on Windows remotely through SSH) does not look like a good idea to me.*

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is (from [Bitvise FAQ](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-usage-faq#Q187)):

> How can I use SSH to start a program so it displays on the server's
> interactive desktop?
>
> The easiest way to do this is using the Windows
> Task Scheduler. First, use the Task Scheduler to configure a task that
> you can run by name. Then run the task from the SSH session using:
>
> ```
> schtasks /run /tn NameOfTask
> ```
>
> If the task runs a PowerShell script or
> batch file, you can also change the contents of the script file on
> demand, to correspond to what you want to run.